# Constant rank theorem for Banach spaces

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control

Is there a similar statement to the constant rank theorem for finite dimensional real smooth manifolds which holds for a smooth map $F:B \rightarrow M$ where $B$ is an infinite (countable) dimensional Banach space and $M$ is a finite dimensional real smooth manifold?

Comment: There are no countable dimensional Banach spaces.

Comment: What about separable Hilbert spaces?

Comment: I meant no countable Hamel basis, of course you can have a countable Schauder basis. I believe, that "x-dimensional" usually refers to Hamel bases. Having a countable Schauder basis is equivalent to separability.

Comment: Ok, that's clear and you are of course correct, thanks.

Comment: @Jochen Wengenroth, a separable Banach space need not have a basis so strictly speaking these two things are not equivalent :-)

Comment: I really only meant separability, a Schauder basis was the basis to which I was referring. I don't think the existence of a Hamel basis will affect my application, but we'll see.

Comment: Yes, I meant Schauder basis too.

Comment: @TomekKania You are of course right. Replying to Benjamin's comment I though of Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is. The (Constant) Rank Theorem for Banach spaces is Theorem 2.5.15 of the book of R. Abraham, J.E. Marsden and T. Ratiu, *Manifolds, Tensor Analysis and Applications* (3rd. edition, Springer-Verlag, 2001). There is a demand that the image of $DF[u_0]$ and the kernel of $DF[u_0]$ are closed direct summands for the $u_0\in B$ around which the theorem holds. The first requirement is automatic if $M$ is finite dimensional (*edit - march 24th 2024:* as well as the second one since in this case, as pointed out by Tobias Diez's comment to Alexander Schmeding's answer, the kernel of $DF[u_0]$ is finite codimensional).

Answer (score 3):

There is also a version of the constant rank theorem in Glöckner's paper "Fundamentals of submersions and immersions between infinite-dimensional manifolds" (Theorem F of [1](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05795.pdf)) which works specifically if the target is a finite-dimensional manifold (and the source an arbitrary manifold modeled on a locally convex space). 
The advantage of having a finite-dimensional target is that one can circumvent most of the tedious assumptions one needs for the case of an infinite-dimensional target (i.e. the ones from the version of Abraham, Marsden and Ratiu).

In [1](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05795.pdf) you can also find some references to constant rank theorems between Banach spaces. They are given after Theorem F.

Comment: Interesting. This means that the hypothesis that $M$ is finite-dimensional also removes the requirement that $\ker DF[u_0]$ should be a closed direct summand. That is very useful. Curiously, Glöckner's paper does not quote the book of Abraham *et al*.

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro: For a finite-dimensional target, the kernel has finite codimension and hence is automatically complemented.

Comment: @TobiasDiez true (and sorry for acknowledging this so late), I've added your remark to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

An improvement to the theorem from the book *Manifolds, Tensor Analysis and Applications* of R. Abraham, J.E. Marsden and T. Ratiu mentioned [above](https://mathoverflow.net/a/204381) was achieved by J. Blot *The Rank Theorem in Infinite Dimension*. The assumption from Abraham et al. is that for every $u$ in a neighborhood of $u_0$ the subspace $DF[u]$ is closed and $DF[u]|_{B_1}$ is an isomorphism thereon, where $B_1$ is a closed complement of the kernel $ B_2 = \ker DF[u_0]$.
It can actually be weekend to the assumption
$$
 \operatorname{Range}(DF[u]) \cap M_2 = \emptyset
$$
where $M_2$ is the closed complement to $M_1 = \operatorname{Range}(DF[u_0]) $.

Note that there is no condition for $DF[u]|_{E_1}$ to be surjective required. Conversely, Abraham et al.'s requirement implies Blot's requirement: Assuming that the intersection is not empty for arbitrarily small neighborhoods, we find $u_n$'s, $y_n$'s and $x_n$'s with $u_n\to u_0$, $y_n \in \operatorname{Range}(DF[u_n]) \cap B_2\setminus\{0\} $, $x_n \in B_1$, and $DF[u_n](x_n) = y_n $.
The set $\{x \in M_2 \mid |x| = 1 \}$ is closed. Hence it has positive Hausdorff distance from $M_1$. Hence it's impossible that the distance of $y_n $ to $M_1$ vanishes as $n\to \infty$. This gives a contradiction.