# Regular value theorem for Banach manifolds without surjectivity

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, banach-manifold

It is well-known (e.g. [Lang, Fundamentals of differential geometry, Prop. 2.3 in Chapter II](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0541-8)) that the following extension of the regular value theorem holds for Banach manifolds:

> Let $\phi : M\rightarrow N$ be a $C^k$-map between two Banach manifolds and let $y\in N$ be so that at every $x\in \phi^{-1}(y)$, the kernel of the differential $d\phi_x$ splits (i.e. can be complemented by a closed subspace) and $d\phi_x$ is surjective. Then $\phi^{-1}(y)$ is a (Banach) $C^k$-submanifold of $X$.

But what if $d\phi_x: T_xM\rightarrow T_y N$ is at every $x\in \phi^{-1}(y)$ not necessarily surjective, but something "a bit worse". For example, what if there exists a fixed Banach space $X$ so that $\operatorname{im}(d\phi_x)\cong X$ at every $x\in \phi^{-1}(y)$?

Comment: @PietroMajer Thank you for reminding me, I totally forgot to add that part ^^

Comment: Note that $\Phi\subset M$ being a  *submanifold* also implies by definition that  $T_p\Phi$ is a *complemented* subspace of $T_p M$.

Comment: This will fail even in the finite dimensional case, say for functions whose derivative vanishes identically on the zero-level set.

Comment: What you really want is an analogue of the constant rank theorem for smooth maps of Banach spaces, see the references given in the answers here:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204378/constant-rank-theorem-for-banach-spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues in infinite dimensions such as not all linear  subspaces are closed  etc.   So I will  state the result  in finite dimensions first.

Suppose $F:M\to N$ is a smooth map between  smooth manifolds (the regularity can be relaxed) and $S\subset N$ is a proper submanifold (it is a closed subset of $N$) We say that  $F$ is transversal to $S$ if for any $x\in M$ such that $F(x)\in S$,  we have

$$ 
D_x F(T_xM)+T_{F(x)} S= T_{F(x)} N.
$$
More about transversality  [here](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Elnicolae/TopicsFall2011-Intersect.pdf). Then  $F^{-1}(S)$ is a submanifold of $M$. This more general result reduces  to the implicit function theorem.   The implicit function theorem  corresponds to the simplest case when $S$ consists of a single point.

**Comment.** Without surjectivity  of the differential things can get tricky. The best one can hope for is so called Kuranishi  description  requiring  for example the map be Fredholm. Here is a finite dimensional example. $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$.

Consider
$\phi:\bR^2\oplus \bR^2\to\bR^2\oplus\bR$ given by
$$
\bR^2\oplus \bR^2\ni (x,y)\mapsto \phi(x,y)= (x,P(y))\in\bR^2\oplus \bR
$$
where $P:\bR^2\to\bR$ is a polynomial map in the variables $y=(y_1,y_2)$.

If $P=0$, then $\phi^{-1}(0)$ is the $2$-plane $0\oplus \bR^2$.

If $P(y)=(y_1-y_2)(y_1+y_2)$, then  $\phi^{-1}(0)$ is the union of two lines, $y_2=\pm y_1$. This is a $1$-dimensional algebraic set with a singularity at the origin.

In both cases the image of $d\phi(0)$ is $\mathbb{R}^2\oplus 0$.  The map $P:\bR^2\to\bR$ is an example of Kuranishi map.

This example is in a sense universal. If $\phi$ is Fredholm  then the zero set of $\phi$ is locally the zero set of a nonlinear map between finite dimensional spaces, the so called Kuranishi map.

Comment: Does it really address the question? OP is asking about preimage of a singleton, in which case transversality is the same as regularity, same as surjectivity of the derivative.

Comment: I'll add a comment to my answer.